# HTML-I need a html and javascript code to upload a docx file and save it in local directory?

Tags: javascript, html, file

I want the code to be written purely in html/javascript and no php or asp. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Upload it to what? A server running node, I hope. Not sure how else you can upload something with only JavaScript.

Comment: you will be needing some server side scripting if you want to upload the file on the server

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy yeah...

Comment: How about our old friend, ActiveX?

Comment: Maybe he is using `node.js`?

Comment: You should always show What code you have tried??

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to I am afraid, JavaScript and HTML run on the client and will not be able to deliver anything to the server without a backend scripting language

Answer (score 0):

A "local directory" is on a server. You cannot save something to a server without server side code (i.e. node.js, PHP, etc).